# When I start VirtualBox 4.2 via terminal, what do the warnings mean?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox

When I start VirtualBox in the terminal, these warning messages show up:

```
Qt WARNING: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "" under id 16 
Qt WARNING: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "&Pause" under id 17 
Qt WARNING: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "&Reset" under id 18 
Qt WARNING: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "D&iscard saved state..." under id 24 
Qt WARNING: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "Re&fresh..." under id 25 
Qt WARNING: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "Show in File Manager" under id 27 
Qt WARNING: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "Create Shortcut on Desktop" under id 28
```

What do they mean?

Answer (score 2):

That's [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) (a GUI framework) related > GUI of the VirtualBox manager. It should not compromise the VirtualBox instance or the guests running in the VirtualBox instance.

My guess is that you can safely ignore those warnings, as they indicate some flaw in the GUI implementation of the VirtualBox interface.